# Container not picking up when using docker image from registry rabbitmq:3.5.3-management

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, windows-10

Command used

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
```

Container is not picked up

---

Also when I am using

docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:latest

Container is picked up in this case but rabbitmq is not started in container
possible reason ( 3 plugins of rabbitmq is started in container not the 4th)

Can anyone help me on this ?

My System os is : Windows 10
Java on local : 11

Comment: You can get a list of docker containers with `docker ps -a`. Then from the list get the id of rabbitmq that failed to start and run `docker logs id`. This will show the issue you are having with starting up

Comment: @ZoltanErsek already tried. Not workiing
sha256:6d6478982831b7fca719c3925ac43ca7e1160ebe32e17c9485f15134fc7d76ab
Status: Downloaded newer image for rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
589e2267ac7c72532a92d68bc8864d21b7bea60c9580b0e3293c0b7033c0c7e6
PS C:\Users\shingari> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
589e2267ac7c   rabbitmq:3.5.3-management   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 seconds  Exited (139) 4 seconds ago             some-rabbit
PS C:\Users\shingari> docker logs 589e2267ac7c

Comment: No logs are generated.

Comment: This looks to me as a configuration issue related to your docker installation. 139 exit code means the container received a SIGSEGV. Your command is working fine on my linux docker installation and rabbitmq starts up successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the reason why your Rabbit doesn't work, first you need to execute

```
docker ps
```

here you will be able to see container id, for example: `589e2267ac7c`

then look at logs

```
docker logs -f 589e2267ac7c
```

so, I think you will see the reason in the log